# About RandomGenerator

Tags: java, eclipse

I was trying to understand a java code which aimed to find the guess number. The point I couldn't get is the following statement.Especially the one starts with rgen.nextInt

```
randNum = rgen.nextInt (lowerBound, upperBound);
```

what does rgen.nextInt refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`randNum` is going to be a random number.

And this

```
rgen.nextInt(lowerBound, upperBound)
```

generates your random number. It is going to be an int value between lowerBound and upperBound

EDIT:
This might also clarify the answer a little more
http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/complete/acm/util/RandomGenerator.html

Comment: I haven't yet encountered usage of this class, and multiple answers on Stack about generating random numbers within bounds recommend writing your own method like that based on util.Random. It's a good guess but I don't think question gives enough information to be sure that's the implementation for this method that is used.

Comment: You might be right. This just seemed like the most obvious one.